# client/server socket reconnection

Tags: sockets, delphi, ibm-midrange

I developed a client/server application based on sockets.

The client side is in Delphi. The server side is on an IBM I (as400)

Sometimes, the client and the server get disconnected. I'm not really sure why, but I think it's because of a machine between them (a proxy, a router, a firewall) sending a `RST` packet.

Anyway, I'm trying to reconnect the client with the same process on the server. (not another one, the same, that's important).

To do that, I create a new connection from the client.  So, I have two processes on the server. I'll call them the "LostProcess" and the "HelperProcess".

The LostProcess is waiting for data in a data queue.

The client tells the HelperProcess that it was connected to the LostProcess.

The HelperProcess sends data to the LostProcess (via the data queue).

The HelperProcess makes a giveDescriptor, and the LostProcess makes a takeDescriptor.

Then the HelperProcess stops and the LostProcess sends data to the client (to say “I'm back”).

So far, it works, but when the client sends data , the LostProcess (we can call it the RebornProcess now) never receives them (I tried not to stop the HelperProcess, and that he is who receives the data).

With Wireshark, I could see that the client sends data with a different local port, so I guess that's why the RebornProcess does not receive them.

I tried to force the local port of the new client socket to be the same as the first one, but then the new client socket cannot connect for a while, and if I wait long enough, I have the same problem as before.

Does somebody have an idea how to make the reconnection work?

Comment: I can't make sense of the problem unless you're saying that the data is successfully sent and received, except that it's received by the `HelperProcess`. And that makes sense. As long as HelperProcess continues to service the data queue, that's a likely place for the sent data to end up. Exactly as designed.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is generally not possible.  Once a TCP connection has been lost, it is gone forever.  Both apps **must** close their respective sockets for the lost connection, and the client app **must** create a new socket connection to continue exchanging data with the server.

If the client app wants to reuse the same local port via `bind()` (which is generally not advisable in most cases), but does not want to wait for the OS to release the port first, then the client can enable the `SO_REUSEADDR` option via `setsockopt()` on the new socket before calling `bind()` and `connect()`.

Comment: I found a solution. the lost client listen to a new port, and the helper process tells to the client on wich port to re connect.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the answer is you can't.

There'd be all kinds of security issues if TCP/IP allowed a new connection to reconnect to an existing processes connection.

You should have the lost process terminate and just use the new process instead.